# Identical matrices causing different results when zooming ImageView

Tags: android, android-imageview

When zooming an imageview, I allow the image to become smaller than the minimum size while pinch zooming, and then in the `onScaleEnd` method restore to the minimum size. However I am running into a problem:

There is no difference between the statement`transformMatrix = new Matrix()` and `transformMatrix = child.getImageMatrix()` in the constructor - I've checked and both assignments will return the matrix: [1, 0, 0][0, 1, 0][0, 0, 1]...  but for some reason **they don't work the same**.

Here is where the image gets scaled:

```
public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        //update the current scale
        float oldScaleFactor = scaleFactor;
        scaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();


        if(Math.abs(oldScaleFactor - scaleFactor) < 0.02 * scaleFactor){
            // don't update scale Factor if the event isn't being handled
            scaleFactor = oldScaleFactor; 
            return false; 
            // should prevent against changes from resting fingers in place
        }
        else{    
             float xDiff = initialFocalPoints[0] - currentFocalPoints[0];
             float yDiff = initialFocalPoints[1] - currentFocalPoints[1];

            transformMatrix.setScale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor,
                               currentFocalPoints[0], currentFocalPoints[1]);
            transformMatrix.postTranslate(xDiff, yDiff);

            child.setImageMatrix(transformMatrix);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Here is where i resize to the correct minimum:

```
@Override
public void onScaleEnd(ScaleGestureDetector detector){
        //making sure the zoom level is within the allowable bounds
        if(scaleFactor < ZOOM_LEVEL_5 || scaleFactor > 8.0f){
        scaleFactor = Math.max(ZOOM_LEVEL_5, Math.min(scaleFactor, 8.0f));
        float xDiff = initialFocalPoints[0] - currentFocalPoints[0];
        float yDiff = initialFocalPoints[1] - currentFocalPoints[1];

        transformMatrix.setScale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor,
                           currentFocalPoints[0], currentFocalPoints[1]);
        transformMatrix.postTranslate(xDiff, yDiff);


        child.setImageMatrix(transformMatrix);
    }
}
```

Everything works fine when I set `transformMatrix = new Matrix()` in the constructor, but this doesn't work for `transformMatrix = child.getImageMatrix()` - the image dosesn't pop back to the correct minimum size... What's going on?

help!

**EDIT**:
Here is the constructor and `onScaleBegin`

```
public ScaleListener(){
        super();
        transformMatrix = new Matrix();
        transformMatrix = child.getImageMatrix();
        inverseTransformMatrix = new Matrix();
        currentFocalPoints = new float[2];
}

@Override
    public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector detector){

        float startX = detector.getFocusX() + getScrollX();
        float startY = detector.getFocusY() + getScrollY();

        initialFocalPoints = new float[]{startX, startY};

        if(transformMatrix.invert(inverseTransformMatrix))
            inverseTransformMatrix.mapPoints(currentFocalPoints, initialFocalPoints);

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Please include all of the relevant code.  You have not shown where you are setting `transformMatrix`.  Also understand that the matrix `[1, 0, 0][0, 1, 0][0, 0, 1]`, also known as the identity matrix, will do nothing.  I don't believe that they do not do the same thing if they are the same matrix so there is more going on here than the code you have shown, and your post, suggests.  I suspect that you are applying the identity matrix to the "too small" image which of course, will remain "too small".

Comment: I understand that the identity matrix does nothing, but there are a lot of calls I make that modify it. It doesn't make any sense to me either, but it's definitely happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still haven't determined WHY this is happening, but I was able to solve this problem by calling `transformMatrix = new Matrix(child.getImageMatrix())`. This way it contains an copy of the child imageView matrix and can be modified.